# Chart.js - cannot fetch result from MySQL via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I am trying to populate a chart via the ChartJS plugin with data from my MySQL database, but while doing so I am running into a

> mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in ...

error.Since I am using json_encode I tried to adjust the fetch array but cant seem to figure this one out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="chart">

        <canvas id="canvas_bar" style="height:250px"></canvas>

        <?php
        // Start MySQLi connection
        $db = new MySQLi($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
        if ($db->connect_errno) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error; }

        // count all records per month
        $sql = "SELECT LOWER(MONTHNAME(mod_date)) AS mdate, count(*) AS cnt FROM qci_modreport GROUP BY LOWER(MONTHNAME(mod_date))";

        if (!($result)) {
            print "ERROR, something wrong with the query.";
        } else {
            $output = array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $output[$row['mdate']] = $row['cnt'];
            }
            print (json_encode($output));
        }
        ?>

        <!-- chartJS 1.0.1-->
        <!-- <script src="./plugins/chartjs/Chart.js"></script> -->
        <script src="../../plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>  
        <script>
            var barChartData = {
                labels: <?php echo json_encode(array_keys($output)); ?>,
                datasets: [
                        {
                            fillColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.5)
                            strokeColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.8)
                            highlightFill: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,0.75)
                            highlightStroke: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,1)
                            data: <?php echo json_encode(array_values($output)); ?>
                }]
            };
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    new Chart($("#canvas_bar").get(0).getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
                        tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
                        responsive: true,
                        barDatasetSpacing: 6,
                        barValueSpacing: 5
                    });
                });



        </script>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
```

Comment: You have three queries and you arbitrarily execute only one of them. Is that right?

Comment: ah, sorry, you can ignore that part. I was just playig around with the sql statement since I couldnt get any data at all in the beginning. I just need one query to count the records of each month and group them.

Comment: Please simplify your code to the minimum that demonstrates the error you are having. Asking us to ignore anything you have posted and leaving in commented out code experiments is not showing respect for the people you are asking for help from. Give the **minimum** amount of code that generates the error you want help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is not defined. You should use

```
if (!($result = $db->query($sql1))) { ...
```

or

`$result = $db->query($sql1);`

and only after you do

`if (!$result) { ...`

and

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ...`

Comment: Doing an  assignment inside an `if` is a great way to annoy your co-workers as that's usually a mistake, and often a big one. This is usually best done on another line, then tested subsequently with an `if`.

Comment: of course it had to be something simple... I adjusted the code and get a $result, but the chart is not populated with labels and data. Updated the code to reflect changes.

Comment: @Armitage2k I think, you incorrectly fills `$output`. May be you should `$output[$row['mdate']] = $row[$row['cnt']]` instead of `array_push($output, $row);`.

Comment: @Armitage2k So `$sql` should be `$sql = "SELECT LOWER(MONTHNAME(mod_date)) AS mdate, count(*) AS cnt FROM qci_modreport GROUP BY LOWER(MONTHNAME(mod_date))";`

Comment: @Gesha that throws me an undefined index error for cnt and mdate and returns $output as null.

Comment: I had typo: `$output[$row['mdate']] = $row['cnt']`. But i don't know why you have udefined index error if you use my sql from previous comment...

Comment: @Gesha why dont you head over to the pub tonight and have a drink on me mate? Thanks a lot, its all working now!